# How to import module from project root?

Tags: webpack

Instead of this:

```
import Foo from ../../../../../../Foo.js
```

I want to do it like this:

```
import Foo from @/Foo.js
```

Is this possible in webpack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible with [`resolve.alias` option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias):

```js
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '@': '/path/to/parent/of/Foo'
  }
}
```